# Searching data of laravel meta table of type metable

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, metadata, meta, polymorphic-associations

I have 3 tables users, articles and metas. I had defined the morphTo() and morphToMany() according to the laravel 5.3 doc and I can pull any particular property of either the user or article defined in the metas table such as firstname or lastname or coordinate.

Now am having difficulties writing the correct model to search these properties e.g a search for any user's firstname or lastname or both.

```
<u>User table</u>
id.    username.    password
1.      Test.             Testpass

<u>article</>
id.   Title.                     Slug
1.     My article title.   my-article-title
```

Metas table

```
Id.     key.                value.                 metable_id    metable_type
1       firstname      Ade                     1                      App\User
2.      content.        Sample article   1.                     App\Article
3.      lastname.     Keon.                   1.                    App\User
```

Meta.php extract

```
public function metable() {
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

User.php extract

```
public function meta() {
    return $this->morphToMany('App\User', 'metable');
}

public function getName() {
     $user = User::find($this->id);
     $metadata = $user->meta()->whereIn('key', ['firstname', 'lastname']) ;
     dd($metadata);
}
```

Article.php extract

```
public function meta() {
    return $this->morphToMany('App\User', 'metable');
}
```

The getName function worked as expected but I can't figure out how to do a search of the user metadata unlike the conventional php/mysql table joins

Dont know how as the whole polymorphic relationship in laravel is new to me but I found and used something like these:

```
public function getSearch() {
      return User::with(array('metas' => function($query) { 
            $query->where('value', $query); 
      }));
 }
```

or

```
public function getSearch() {
         return User::with('metas') 
         ->whereHas('metas', function($query) { 
                $query->where('value', '=', $query); 
          });
   }
```

I cant see or reason how to join the tables in laravel

here is my new search query

```
public function getResults(Request $request) {
    $keyword = $request->input('query');
    $filterOne = $request->input('minAge');
    $filterTwo = $request->input('maxAge');

    $query = User::with(['meta' => function ($q) {
        $q->where('value', 'like', $keyword)
            ->orWhere(function ($q) {
                $q->whereBetween('value', [$filterOne,$filtertwo]);
            });
    }])->get();

dd($query);
}
```

Comment: Please describe what have you tried and what is not working.

Comment: Show your database schema and your relationships.

Comment: @TheFallen I had updated d question as advised

Comment: @sitechum what do you mean by *how to do a search of the user metadata*? Please describe what do you expect to get as an end result.

Comment: Evening everyone, I still need that help and I hope d question is clear enough

Comment: @TheFallen, there is my new search query but i get error with $keyword as undeclare and using dd() I get the right value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the contribution above, the insufficient of this actually push me harder to readings and thinking, I finally came across the `use()` with function query as shown below;

```
public function getResults(Request $request) {
        $keyword = $request->input('query');
        $filterOne = $request->input('minAge');
        $filterTwo = $request->input('maxAge');

        if (isset($keyword)) {
            $query = User::with(['meta' => function ($q) use ($keyword,$filterOne,$filterTwo) {
                $q->where('value', 'LIKE', $keyword)
                    ->whereBetween('value', [$filterOne, $filterTwo]);
            }])->get();
        } else {
            $query = User::with(['meta' => function ($q) use ($filterOne,$filterTwo) {
                $q->whereBetween('value', [$filterOne, $filterTwo]);
            }])->get();
        }

        dd($query);
    }
```

This gives me the result am looking for; though am not sure the effect on performance when dealing with large dataset but then i guess that's my next assignment.